# SceneKit wireframe invisible

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to build a basic SceneKit app, but my node is not visible when I go to the file. However, it becomes visible in orange when i click it. For contrast, my other nodes are visible at all times. Is there some issue about rendering the small lines? Do they have no color?

I converted this SCN file from a DAE, so another possibility is that something is wrong with the process of converting the file, though I have tried with several different converters.

How can I show the lines? Am I missing setting a property or something? I have tried tweaking several of the diffuse settings and using image fills, etc.

[image: Only shows orange selection lines]

Comment: Could be either the transparency (check material inspector), or white over white color (add a light to make sure).